# validating an xml file against a local dtd

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to validate an xml file against a local dtd.

Here is the example code taken from a book:

```
    dtd = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(%{<!ELEMENT rubycookbook (recipe+)>
    <!ELEMENT recipe (title?, problem, solution, discussion, seealso?)+>
    <!ELEMENT titlexx (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT problem (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT solution (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT discussion (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT seealso (#PCDATA)>})


    open('cookbook.xml', 'w') do |f|
      f.write %{<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <rubycookbook>
       <recipe>
         <title>A recipe</title>
         <problem>A difficult/common problem</problem>
         <solution>A smart solution</solution>
         <discussion>A deep solution</discussion>
         <seealso>Pointers</seealso>
       </recipe>
      </rubycookbook>
      }
    end

document = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('cookbook.xml'))
document.external_subset.validate
```

When I run the command below,

> document.external_subset.validate

I get the following error message:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `validate' for nil:NilClass

'document.external_subset' returns me nil.

Can anyone advise me on this issue? Thanks

Comment: Surely that should be something like `document.create_external_subset(...); document.validate`?

Comment: You never associated that DTD with the XML, and you're trying to validate the DTD rather than the XML!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892851/1954610

Comment: I am very new to Nokogiri and I am not familiar with the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

dtd = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(%{<!ELEMENT rubycookbook (recipe+)>
    <!ELEMENT recipe (title?, problem, solution, discussion, seealso?)+>
    <!ELEMENT titlexx (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT problem (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT solution (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT discussion (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT seealso (#PCDATA)>})

open('cookbook.xml', 'w') do |f|
  f.write %{<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <rubycookbook>
   <recipe>
     <title>A recipe</title>
     <problem>A difficult/common problem</problem>
     <solution>A smart solution</solution>
     <discussion>A deep solution</discussion>
     <seealso>Pointers</seealso>
   </recipe>
  </rubycookbook>
  }
end

the_dtd = Nokogiri::XML::DTD.new('dtd', dtd)
document = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('cookbook.xml'))
p the_dtd.validate(document)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am getting 'no root element'. Any idea?

Comment: I replicated your error and fixed it by adding the above using nokogiri 1.8.1 on ruby 2.4.0

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error when I do  'puts document.external_subset.validate(dtd)'

Comment: Is it because of my nokogiri version?, I am using version 1.6.8.1. I will try upgrading it

Comment: I had a look at the book but it says to use document.validate, then uses document.external_subset.validate so I'm not sure if the code does anything. I've updated the answer and it shows a validation error rather than a system error